# cts:reference on document properties

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I want to use cts:values-co-occurrence on the document properties, so I was wondering if I can create a cts:refrence on the document properties. 
I am trying to de-duplicate search results for faceting purposes.. All my documents have a property called `<id>` .. But I want for frequency calculation only use 1 per `<id>`, but my database has for each original document has some artifact documents but all of them have the property `<id>`. so I was thinking of using the cts:value-co-occurrence for de-duplicating .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can just use `cts:element-reference`, regardless of whether it's a document fragment or a property fragment. Then in your call to `cts:value-co-occurences`, pass an empty properties fragment query as the fourth parameter:

```
cts:properties-fragment-query(cts:and-query(()))
```

Comment: The [cts:value-co-occurrences](http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:value-co-occurrences) function also takes the `"properties"` and the `"any"` option to search through properties fragments, or both document and properties fragments..

Comment: I tried the following <br/>

`let $m := cts:value-co-occurrences(
              cts:element-reference(xs:QName('id')),
             cts:uri-reference(),
              'map,Properties')` <br/>
and it gives me <br/>
`cts:element-reference(fn:QName("","id")) -- No element range index for id http://marklogic.com/collation/`
<br/>
How do I create element range index for properties of a document ??

Comment: @Ravi You only need to create a range index on the element QName. MarkLogic will automatically index *both* document and properties fragments.